# TV Pine Script - Strategy - Sell and Close signals are placed incorrectly

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

My strategy is to catch the downtrend and for this I'm checking if open[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmqPf.png) < open[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trbkh.png) and if current candle opens lower than previous then generate sell signal.

Exit when any candle opens higher than it's previous candle's open, following is the script and I've attached the screenshot too

**This is my expectation:**

[image]

**But this is what the script is doing:**

[image]

**Here is my script:**

```
//EMA5 alert
//@version=5
strategy("Lower lows Sell", overlay=true)


// Check if previous candle's open is lower than previous previous and current candle's open is lower than previous
// It means it's a downtrend
sellSignal = (open[1] < open[2]) and open < open[1]
// assume downtrend ends when a candle open higher than open of previous candle
exitSignal = open > open[1]



// Strategy entry and exit
if (sellSignal)
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)
if (exitSignal)
    strategy.close("Sell")
```

Also, the close signal text is long and weird, how to change it like **Exit**

Thanks

I tried looking at the code of some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your orders will be executed on the open of the next candle. To change this, you can set `process_orders_on_close` to `true` in your `strategy()` call.

You can use the `comment` argument of the `strategy.close()` in order to change the close order message you see on your chart.